# Using jQuery DataTables Editable to edit multiple values

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I'm using the [jQuery DataTables Editable](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/) to be able to edit data in a table.

The table is looking like this:

[image]

As you can see I have one column with multiple values, when clicking on this column I want to be able to edit all fields like this:

[image]

Is it possible to customize the jQuery DataTables Editable to handle multiple values like this? I haven't found any examples, maybe you can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do thatyou should provide the correct markup. for example you could do something like this

HTML

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Rendering engine</th>

        <th>Browser</th>

        <th>Platform(s)</th>

        <th>Engine version</th>

        <th>CSS grade</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr id="1" class="gradeX">
        <td>Trident</td>

        <td>Internet Explorer 4.0</td>

        <td>Win 95+</td>

        <td class="center">4</td>

        <td class="center">
              <div class='editable'>line 1</div>
              <div class='editable'>Line 2</div>
          </td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="2" class="gradeC">
        <td>Trident</td>

        <td>Internet Explorer 5.0</td>

        <td>Win 95+</td>

        <td class="center">5</td>

        <td class="center">              
            <div class='editable'>line 1</div>
            <div class='editable'>Line 2</div>
          </td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="3" class="gradeA">
        <td>Trident</td>

        <td>Internet Explorer 5.5</td>

        <td>Win 95+</td>

        <td class="center">5.5</td>

          <td class="center">
              <div class='editable'>line 1</div>
              <div class='editable'>Line 2</div>
          </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

js

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
$('td div.editable', oTable).editable('../examples_support/editable_ajax.php', {
    "callback": function(sValue, y) {
        var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);
        oTable.fnUpdate(sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1]);
    },
    "submitdata": function(value, settings) {
        return {
            "row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id'),
            "column": oTable.fnGetPosition(this)[2]
        };
    },
    "height": "14px",
    "width": "100%"
});
```

Notice that only the last column is editable and i used two `<div>` and selected them with $('td div.editable', oTable)

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GhgLW/2/

Comment: ..I need your help regarding this editor issue...please let me know your email,if you are ok with that..